# Clothing stays in place when body starts moving

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

Recently i started using cloth sims for clothing. I downloaded a low res human model with animation and modeled a t-shirt for it. Everything worked just fine. I then used the MB-Lab adon to create a better looking human model and animated it. But when i try a cloth sim now it doesnt work. I have the model animated so it stays still in T-Pose for a while and during that time the sim is fine. But as soon as the animation starts the cloth sims breaks. The human model moves but my shirt stays in the same place as if nothing had happened. The cloth sim is still working but it looks as if the model was still standing in T-pose, while in fact it is moving. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you parented your cloth to the armature ?

Comment: I didnt know i needed to do that. When i used the low poly model i didnt have to parent anything it just worked. How would i parent the cloth to the armature? (Sry real begginer here)

Comment: I'm not really experienced with that either, but you parent it to the armature by clicking on the object first and then shift click on your armature. Then, control P. I would parent with empty groups in this case, and then, you're good for a weight painting session :D
Be sure that your armature modifier is above the cloth one though.

Comment: Worked on MB_Lab character yesterday. You shouldn't parent cloth with armature unless you have a vertex group "pinned", in which case you'd want to parent the pin area to the armature, with weight painting around the pinned vertices.   It sounds like you have your characters MESH as a Collision object.   You may need to play around with decreasing the Collision "Inner" and "Friction" from the defaults, and some messing with Cloth params Quality Steps, Collisons *Quality*.  Consider if you need a Solidify modifier *above* either the character Collision mod or cloth objects Cloth modifier stack.